# How to Transform Form recognizer JSON structure into SQL table

Tags: json, azure-data-factory, azure-form-recognizer

I have below JSON structure which is returned by Azure Form Recognizer API.

**columnCount** key gives actual number of columns.

I want to transform the cells where Kind = columnHeader into Column of Azure SQL table

And rest of cells where Kind = null should convert into Rows

What is the best way to achieve this in ADF ?

1. Use Flatten Activity in ADF
2. Write Transformation logic using loops in Azure Function and return a CSV string
3. Use libraries like JUST.NET inside Azure Functions

**Note** : Number of rows and columns returned from Form recognizer will be dynamic

{
"rowCount": 9,
"columnCount": 2,
"cells": [{
"kind": "columnHeader",
"rowIndex": 0,
"columnIndex": 0,
"rowSpan": 1,
"columnSpan": 1,
"content": "ColumnA",
"boundingRegions": [{
"pageNumber": 5,
"boundingBox": [0.4461,
7.7151,
3.7924,
7.7151,
3.7924,
7.968,
0.4461,
7.968]
}],
"spans": [{
"offset": 6640,
"length": 9
}]
},
{
"kind": "columnHeader",
"rowIndex": 0,
"columnIndex": 1,
"rowSpan": 1,
"columnSpan": 1,
"content": "ColumnB",
"boundingRegions": [{
"pageNumber": 5,
"boundingBox": [3.7924,
7.7151,
7.1799,
7.7151,
7.1799,
7.968,
3.7924,
7.968]
}],
"spans": [{
"offset": 6650,
"length": 9
}]
},
{
"rowIndex": 1,
"columnIndex": 0,
"rowSpan": 1,
"columnSpan": 1,
"content": "Cell1Value",
"boundingRegions": [{
"pageNumber": 5,
"boundingBox": [0.4461,
7.968,
3.7924,
7.968,
3.7924,
8.195,
0.4461,
8.195]
}],
"spans": [{
"offset": 6660,
"length": 18
}]
},
{
"rowIndex": 1,
"columnIndex": 1,
"rowSpan": 1,
"columnSpan": 1,
"content": "Cell2Value",
"boundingRegions": [{
"pageNumber": 5,
"boundingBox": [3.7924,
7.968,
7.1799,
7.968,
7.1799,
8.195,
3.7924,
8.195]
}],
"spans": [{
"offset": 6679,
"length": 18
}]
},
]
}

**Output should Look like this**

**ColumnA , ColumnB**

Cell1Value, Cell2Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example that had worked for me and was achieved by using the flatten and aggregate transformations.

When flattening, unroll by 'cells'.

[Flatten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OISHS.png)

[FlattenDataPreview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Y8c.png)

Then, in the aggregate transformation, group by rowIndex and aggregate by text with this expression:

replace(trim(trim(toString(collect(text)),'['),']'),'"','')

[AggregateDataPreview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGWyq.png)

If you wanted to continue to use dataflow to set up your table, you can create derived columns and set SQL as your sink.

[TableDataPreview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBdfh.png)

Alternatively, you can save to storage and then use the copy activity in your pipeline.

Comment: THanks @Noelle
Right now , I am transforming Formrecognizer output JSON into Key/Value structure by calling Azure Function. I call Azure Function from Web Activity , when I try to do the same from COPY data activity the call fails

Comment: @Sagar would you be able to show your pipeline and what error you're getting?